# Simplest GR geometrical model for bending of light

Tags: general-relativity, gravity, visible-light, geodesics

How to find orbit of bent light in the simplest gravity model by solving the null geodesic equation either by Newton's physical or by Einstein's GR?

[Bent Light](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/383704/)

To compare we have the simplest model of a two body problem for planetary motion.. (without any Lagrange points of Three Body gravitational dynamics and more)

Comment: This is a standard, easily-found derivation. For example, see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarzschild_geodesics#Bending_of_light_by_gravity).

Comment: Thanks for the reference.